# include dictionary or array value in swift string with backslash notation

Tags: swift

I'm testing out the playground for swift reading the ebook and am testing the backslash insert value into string thing..
wondering how I could do this with a dictionnary array, but it does not seem to like it.

```
var str="dictionary values are \(dict['mine'])"
```

this errors out.
just wondering what the correct way to escape this would be, or should I just concatenate them in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quotes are not allowed as string delimiters in Swift. Additionally the string interpolation does not allow ‘unescaped double quote (") or backslash (\)’, cf. [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_382)

If you have the key as a constant (or variable) it will work:

```
let key = "mine"
let str = "dictionary values are \(dict[key])"
```

As an aside Swift encourages immutability for safety, you should always use `let` by default and only revert to `var` if you really need to.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've been able to tell there isn't a way. You just have to break it up onto multiple line, like so:

```
let x = dict["mine"]
var str="dictionary values are \(x)"
```